# How to stop function from going off if Wolf strength < 1

Tags: javascript, html

So i have a function tied to a radio button that while the radio button is on stats are buffed. But the problem is if i switch buttons from my turtle pet to my lizard pet  my strength goes down by 1 when it shouldn't change at all.

https://prnt.sc/nvogfc

I've tried a few if statements but none of them are giving me the outcome i want.

This is my code:

```js
var Wolf = 1;
var Wolflv = 1;
var WolfCexp = 0;
var WolfMexp = 100;
var NextMaxWolfExp = WolfMexp;
var Strength = 2;
var Wolfstrength = 1

function Wolfandstrength() {
  if (document.getElementById("wolf-radio").checked) {
    Strength = Strength + Wolfstrength
    document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;
  } else {
    Strength = Strength - Wolfstrength
    document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;
  }
}

function wolfXpUp() {
  if (document.getElementById("wolf-radio").checked && WolfCexp <
    WolfMexp) {
    setTimeout(wolfXpUp, 200)
    WolfCexp = WolfCexp + 1;
    document.getElementById("WolfCexp").innerHTML = WolfCexp;
  }
  if (WolfCexp >= WolfMexp) {
    Wolflv = Wolflv + 1;
    WolfCexp = 0;
    Wolf = Wolf + 1;
    Wolfstrength = Wolfstrength + 1;
    Strength = Strength + 1;
    NextMaxWolfExp = NextMaxWolfExp * 1.5;
  }
  document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;
  document.getElementById('WolfMexp').innerHTML = NextMaxWolfExp;
  document.getElementById('Wolflv').innerHTML = Wolflv;
  document.getElementById('WolfCexp').innerHTML = WolfCexp;
  document.getElementById('Wolf').innerHTML = Wolf;
}
document.getElementById("wolf-radio").addEventListener("change",
  wolfXpUp)
document.getElementById("wolf-radio").addEventListener("change",
  Wolfandstrength)
document.getElementById("lizard-radio").addEventListener("change",
  Wolfandstrength);
document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;
```

```html
<div id="turtle" class="control">
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="Pets" id="turtle-radio">
  </label><img src="turtle.png" alt="turtle" height="100" width="100"> Lv <span id="Turtlelv">1</span> <span id="TurtleCexp">0</span> / <span id="TurtleMexp">100</span>
  <br />
  <br />

  <div id="lizard" class="control">
    <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="Pets" id="lizard-radio">
    </label><img src="lizard.png" alt="lizard" height="42" width="42"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Lv <span id="Lizardlv">1</span> <span id="LizardCexp">0</span> / <span id="LizardMexp">100</span>
    <br />
    <div id="wolf" class="control">
      <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="Pets" id="wolf-radio">
      </label><img src="wolf.png" alt="wolf" height="60" width="60"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Lv <span id="Wolflv">1</span> <span id="WolfCexp">0</span> / <span id="WolfMexp">100</span></div>
    <br />
    <span id="Strength">0</span>
```

I expect when switching from the turtle radio button to the lizard one for my strength to not go down. I would assume adding a if statement to the function Wolfandstrength   would fix this, but the actual output when i change from turtle to lizard it takes away 1 strength. Strength should be equal to it’s starting value before the wolf radio button is selected. I have that function connected to the lizard one so if you switch from wolf to lizard it correctly changes strength back to its base. I need if statements to help when it comes to changing to other buttons. I think preventing Wolfstrength from going negative would fix this.

Comment: When you click on the lizard button, it runs `Wolfandstrength()`. That function does `Strength = Strength - Wolfstrength` when the wolf button isn't checked.

Comment: Do you want to level up `lizard` when `lizard radio` is checked and level up `turtle` when `turtle radio` is checked?

Comment: @pindev nah I just want the turtle to lizard switch of buttons to not make your original strength value go down by 1 if it is going to = 0 or go negative. Not sure how to prevent it from going negative or zero

Comment: Do you mean that you wanna decrease 1 level of lizard when you switch from turtle to lizard but not the negative values?

Comment: You can prevent it going negative with `if (Strength < 0) { Strength = 0; }` after you decrease.

Comment: Meh i tried that. didnt turn out correct

Comment: @Barmar I appreciate the help . Would a true/false switch work to check if the buttons are active then if one is the other buttons are false or get minused . Like var wolfActive =true; var lizardActive =false; var turtleActive = false; I’m not sure how to format the function tho or how to tie those to eatch button. I had someone trying to explain it to me I’ll post more when I get home from work . I think it’s like event listener ( change, then the function that checks what button is active

Comment: It might be better to do something like `activePet = 'wolf';`.

Comment: @Barmar I’ll try some stuff when I get home from work. If u have time could you make up a answer useing true/ false stuff to check if buttons are selected and if not don’t let the function run

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're doing well enough to write an answer, and you seem incapable of explaining it so I can understand. That's why I deleted my old answer, we were going nowhere and I have given up on this question.